# Program that generates 20 random numbers and search the array for a number

Tags: c#, arrays, search, random, int

I want to make a program that generates  20 random numbers and search the array for a number. If one of the 20 random numbers was typed in the input the output should say "it is here". If the number is not in the ReadLine it should say"Yes it is there".I want to know how to make all 20 random numbers to be able to search. The code right now can only search the number on the right. Even if the input is one of the 20 random numbers except for the one on the right it would say "No it is not here."

The picture is my current output.  IT IS SHOWING 20 NUMBERS.[Output1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfRdd.png)[Output2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9qy4.png)

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    int[] myIntArray = new int[100];

    for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
    {
        int x = random.Next(100);

        myIntArray[i] = x;

        Console.Write(myIntArray[i] + " ");

        if (i == 20)
        {

            Console.Write("\nType a number to search for:");
            int z = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if (z == x)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Yes it is there.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No it is not here.");
            }

        }
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a contains check. For array, you have to use a static function to do that, Exists: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.exists | However it does use the somewhat more complicated advanced checks, rather then a simple equality like "Contains" would.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through with the debugger and trying to see what this code is actually doing? Just based on eyeballing it, it doesn't look like it's all that close to doing what you want it to.

Comment: Typo? `int[] myIntArray = new int[100];` `new int[20];` expected; `for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)` should be `for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)` - arrays are zero based

Comment: You need 3 things: 1. A loop that Initializes the array with random numbers. 2. A way for a user to input the target number. This can include a optional do/while loop, to make sure the user inputs something valid. 3. One loop that checks if the User input is anywhere in the array | Right now you have the input and the check "smeared" all over Loop 1.

Comment: You don't need `if (i == 20)`, simply move user input outside of loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your current code checks if 20tyh item (`x`) is equal to user input (`z`):

```
    if (i == 20) // 20th item only
    {    
        int z = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if (z == x) // if 20th item (x) equals to user input (z)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Yes it is there.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No it is not here.");
        } 
    }
```

Try solving the problem step by step:

1. Declare the array
2. Fill it with random values
3. Print the array out
4. Ask user for a number
5. Perform the search

Code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Array...    
    int[] myIntArray = new int[20]; // We want 20 items, not 100, right? 

    // Of random items
    Random random = new Random(); 

    for (int i = 0; i < myIntArray.Length; ++i)
        myIntArray[i] = random.Next(100);

    // Debug: let's have a look at the array:     
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", myIntArray));

    // myIntArray is built. Time to ask user for a number
    Console.Write("Type a number to search for:");

    if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int number)) {
         // number is a valid integer number, let's scan myIntArray 
         bool found = false;

         foreach (int item in myIntArray)
             if (item == number) {
                 found = true;

                 break; 
             }   

        if (found) 
            Console.WriteLine("Yes it is there.");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("No it is not here.");                
    }
    else 
        Console.WriteLine("Not a valid integer");

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Edit:** In real life, we often use *Linq* to query collections (arrays):

```
using System.Linq;

... 

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Random random = new Random();

    int[] myIntArray = Enumerable
      .Range(0, 20)
      .Select(i => random.Next(100)) 
      .ToArray();   

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", myIntArray));

    Console.Write("Type a number to search for:");

    if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int number)) 
        if (myIntArray.Any(item => item == number)) 
            Console.WriteLine("Yes it is there.");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("No it is not here.");                
    else 
        Console.WriteLine("Not a valid integer");

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So basicly you should make a loop that initialize your array with a random numbers with one array

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
    {
        int x = random.Next(100);

        myIntArray[i] = x;
    }
```

After that you can search for the typed value in console in another loop

```
Console.Write("\nType a number to search for:");
bool isValueFound = false;
int z = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
for(int i=0; i<=20; i++){
    if (z == x)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Yes it is there.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No it is not here.");
            }
}
```

All code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    int[] myIntArray = new int[100];

    for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
    {
        int x = random.Next(100);

        myIntArray[i] = x;
    }
    Console.Write("\nType a number to search for:");
    bool isValueFound = false;
    int z = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    for(int i=0; i<=20; i++){
        if (z == x)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Yes it is there.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No it is not here.");
            }
}
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```