# C# Program that generates 20 random numbers and search the array for a number (Continued)

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, search, int

I am reposting this and edited it because I somehow can't see the answers for the old one.
Old Question:  I want to make a program that generates 20 random numbers and search the array for a number. If one of the 20 random numbers was typed in the input the output should say "it is here". If the number is not in the ReadLine it should say"Yes it is there".I want to know how to make all 20 random numbers to be able to search. The code right now can only search the number on the right. Even if the input is one of the 20 random numbers except for the one on the right it would say "No it is not here."

NEW: I want to make this work by having 2 for loops one for creating an array and 1 for searching the number. I have edited this program to have 2 for loops but the output is strange as you see on the picture. Please help me by editing this code to complete work but still have 2 for loops again one for creating an array and 1 for searching the number.[image: Output1] [image: Output2]

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
{

  Random random = new Random();
  int[] myIntArray = new int[100];


   for (int i=0; i <20; i++)
   {
     int x = random.Next(100);
     myIntArray[i] = x;
     Console.Write(myIntArray[i] + " ");
   } 
    Console.Write("\nType a number to search for:");
    bool isValueFound = false;
    int z = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    for (int i = 0; i <20; i++)
     {

       if (z==myIntArray[i]) 
       {
          Console.WriteLine("Yes it is there.");

       }
      else
          Console.WriteLine("No it is not here.");

       }



    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("No it is not here.");` Should be outside the loop. Only print this after you have checked all numbers and the number is not found. You have the `isValueFound` variable. Use that.

Comment: [Original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61797877/program-that-generates-20-random-numbers-and-search-the-array-for-a-number)

Comment: Use a debugger to step through the last for-loop, you will see what is happening

Comment: consider using an hashset as well, this way you wont have any duplicates. also the hashset will provide you with a contains method to check is the number is present in the set

Answer (score 0):

```
   if (z==myIntArray[i]) 
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Yes it is there.");

   }
   else
      Console.WriteLine("No it is not here.");  <- The problem is here

   }
```

At every number, if it is not a match you are printing 'No'. You should rather utilize `isValueFound` variable that you defined, You can do the following:

1. Don't print anything in the loop
2. When there is a match sent `isValueFound` to true, and break the loop
3. Outside the second loop, check the `isValueFound` to decide whether it is a found or not-found.

Additionally, you have a good opportunity to learn the Binary search as well. Happy coding!